# How do I use org-mode's checkboxes?

Tags: org-mode

I'm unsure how to use checkboxes in Emacs. I'm using Emacs 24.3.

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Checkboxes.html) suggests the use of `org-toggle-checkbox` as "With a single prefix argument, add an empty checkbox..."

I've tried starting with an existing list (with org-mode as the major mode), as in:

```
* shopping list
** eggs
** bread
** Tesla Model S
** bacon
```

Whether I put point in "shopping list", or in "eggs", pressing `C-u C-c C-x C-b` (which runs `org-toggle-checkbox`) results in the error "No item in subtree" being printed to the minibuffer. This behavior happens without my init file (`emacs -Q`), so it's purely an org-mode issue.

What's the right way to start using checkboxes?

Comment: It will toggle it if you use the checkbox syntax like this: ``` 
* shopping list

- [ ] eggs
- [X] bread
- [ ] Tesla Model S
- [X] bacon 
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the manual link states, checkboxes only work in [plain lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Plain-Lists.html).  Your example uses [headlines](http://orgmode.org/manual/Headlines.html).  You need to use the checkboxes this way:

```
* shopping list

  - eggs
  - bread
  - Tesla Model S
  - bacon
```

Now, when you're on "eggs", you can hit `C-u C-c C-c` (`C-u C-c C-x C-b` also works) to toggle the checkbox.  `C-c C-c` will then toggle whether the checkbox is checked or not.

If you are already in a checkbox list, then `M-S-RET` will add a new item with a checkbox.

Comment: You can use `C-c - `  to convert a headline into a plain list entry and `C-c *` to do the opposite.

Comment: It will toggle it if you use the checkbox syntax like this: ``` 
* shopping list

- [ ] eggs
- [X] bread
- [ ] Tesla Model S
- [X] bacon 
```